# Creating GPX XML in Android Java

Tags: android, xml, gpx

I am trying to create a GPX file in Android and can't work out how to create an Element with a value, like the `<ele> or <time>`  elements in the following snippet.

```
  <trkpt lat="-33.626932" lon="151.306745">
    <time>2015-09-12T03:25:00.000Z</time>
    <ele>-6</ele>
  </trkpt>
```

In PHP, I can create an element with a value, like:

```
 $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0");
 $trkpt = $xml->createElement("trkpt");
 $trkpt->appendChild($xml->createElement("ele","-6"));
```

but for the life of me, I can't find an equivalent in Java.
I have tried (removed try/catch for clarity):

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder parser =  factory.newDocumentBuilder(); 
Document xml = parser.newDocument();
Element trkpt = xml.createElement("trkpt");
trkpt.setAttribute("lat", "-33.626932");
trkpt.setAttribute("lon","151.306745"); 
Attr ele = xml.createAttribute("ele");
ele.setNodeValue("-6");
trkpt.setAttributeNode(ele);
```

But that creates :

```
<trkpt lat="-33.626932" lon="151.306745" ele="-6">
```

Which is incorrect GPX syntax.
I would like to avoid building the string from scratch as my files can be very large, 40,000 points.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
    Attr ele = xml.createAttribute("ele");
    ele.setNodeValue("-6");
    trkpt.setAttributeNode(ele);
```

Try :

```
    Element ele = xml.createElement("ele");
    ele.appendChild(xml.createTextNode("-6"));        
    trkpt.appendChild(ele);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, it looks ugly, but here's the answer. I have to add a text node to the `<ele>` Element:

```
Element ele =  xml.createElement("ele");
ele.appendChild(xml.createTextNode("-6"));
trkpt.appendChild(ele);
```